# Example Highcharts in jupyter notebook Inline

Tags: python, highcharts, jupyter-notebook

Can anybody post an example highcharts inline in Jupyter-notebook?

I am looking to use Highcharts inline in a jupyter-notebook

I copy pasted the code here :http://jacobbridges.github.io/post/jupyter-notebook-with-interactive-charts/

But am getting an empty div [image]

Comment: Have you looked at [`python-highcharts`](https://github.com/kyper-data/python-highcharts)? No need to write JS. They have an example [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/kyper-data/python-highcharts/blob/master/examples/ipynb/highcharts/Example1.ipynb).

Comment: @Scatch'N'Purr I have used it a couple of times. But I need to learn and practice the js code.Its convenient to use the notebooks.Can you direct me to the right resources?